# Paradox of Fake Choice

Tags: logic, solution-verification, intuition, paradoxes

This is a logic sort of question, so if it is better suited for a different stack exchange please let me know, not sure if this is the optimal location

I thought of this interesting contradiction / paradox when thinking about some of those door puzzles

> A person walks up to a split in the road that diverges into two paths. At the center of the road there is an all-knowing Oracle that can see into the future. Before deciding which path to take, the Oracle tells the person *"One of these paths is safe, and another leads to certain death. I have seen the future and you will select the path of certain death"*. Does the person's choice of path matter?

If the Oracle is all knowing that would imply that the person's choice *does not* matter. Since the Oracle has forseen that the person *will* choose the deadly path, that means no matter what path the person chooses, it will be the deadly path. However, this contradicts our statement that only one path is a deadly path, so that implies the Oracle cannot be able to see the future?

Is there a problem with my logic / is there a name for this paradox?

Comment: This is probably better for philosophy stack exchange.

Comment: Related: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newcomb%27s_paradox

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know if this "paradox" has a name… but I don’t actually think it’s a paradox (at least as stated when I’m making this comment).

Your logic is flawed.

Say Path S leads to safety, and Path D leads to death. If the Oracle *can* tell the future, and foresees that the person will choose Path D, that doesn’t contradict the statement that only one path is a deadly path.

Comment: The problem comes from using the word "choose" in the question.  That assumes that the person can choose either path.  The fact that there is such an Oracle says that is not true.